# Timezone lookup from latitude longitude

Tags: api

Is there any library (or even better, web service) available which can convert from a latitude/longitude into a time zone?

([Originally asked by Matt Sheppard on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504/1591669))

Comment: See also: [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a small Java class to do this, with the data structure embedded in the code. If you want to avoid using a web service, and accuracy of 2km is good enough, and you're happy to assume that timezone boundaries don't change, then it could help.

https://github.com/drtimcooper/LatLongToTimezone

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Thanx @Michael. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some that I found that you can try for your project.

## Library

#### [Timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone)

> A simple way to get accurate current and historical timezone
> information based on zone or latitude and longitude coordinates. This
> gem uses the tz database for historical timezone information. It also
> uses the geonames API for timezone latitude and longitude lookup.

This is an API for Ruby projects. I haven't try it, since I used web services from **[Google Time API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)** or **TimeZoneDB** (see bellow for more detail on TimeZoneDB) for my own projects.

For other programming languages you can always search GitHub.com.

## Web Service

#### [TimeZoneDB](http://timezonedb.com)

> TimezoneDb provides simple RESTful interface API and
> returns structured XML or JSON responses. Our API converts latitude &
> longitude to time zone data. You also able to retrieve time zone
> information for a specific zone. You need to register a *free* API key
> to start using our services.

You can use **[TimeZoneDB API](http://timezonedb.com/api)** to get time zone information on geographical point, i.e. longitude/latitude or **[time zone name](http://timezonedb.com/time-zones)**. Before you can use it on your own project, you will need to sign up for the *free* service and get an [API key](http://timezonedb.com/register).

Given the longitude/latitude pair or time zone name, the API will response with:

- Error message, if any occured.
- Status: `OK` or `Fail`.
- GMT offset based on UTC time
- [Country code](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes) (e.g. `ID`)
- Time zone name (e.g. `Asia/Jakarta`)
- [Time zone abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)
- [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

I personally used TimeZoneDB and cached the response on my back-end server to be used by a mobile client application.